# Custom route constraint issue in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am going through "Routing Requests for Disk Files" part in Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 book and am facing a bit of a strange problem relating to a custom route constraint.

I created a custom route:

```
//82:1. this is added so that below routes are checked first before checking the disk files.
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;

//82:2 the custom route which maps requests to Static/StaticContent.htm to route /Home/Content, only from IE.
routes.MapRoute("DiskFile", "Content/StaticContent.htm",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Content" },
    new {customConstraint = new UserAgentConstraint("IE")},
    new[] { "UrlsAndRoutes.Controllers" });
```

The book says that this route will let IE users view the Home/Content route and non-IE users view the Content/StaticContent.htm directly. **It is NOT working for me that way.**

Here is what is happening:

1. I run the application and open the URL `http://localhost:50483/Content/StaticContent.htm` in IE and am being re-routed to /Home/Content
2. I then open the URL `http://localhost:50483/Content/StaticContent.htm` in Chrome and am being shown the original content of the StaticContent.htm
3. I then change to IE and press `Ctrl-R` (refresh) OR select URL in url bar and press `Enter` and am routed to original content of the StaticContent.htm (*why?*)
4. If I press `Ctrl-F5`, then, I am being re-routed to /Home/Content (*wut?*)

Isn't the route supposed to send IE users, who try to access Content/StaticContent.htm, always to /Home/Content?

PS: I restarted Visual Studio and also deleted browser history on IE, **but the issue persists**.

[UserAgentConstraint.cs](http://pastebin.mozilla.org/2267630)
[RegisterRoutes method in Global.asax.cs](http://pastebin.mozilla.org/2267631)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's probably being cached**

Ctrl+F5 makes it ask server for reload even if content haven't changed.

It sounds like this is correct behaviour.

Verify by making changes to static.html after first reload. Then Ctrl+R reload. It should hit the action method.

Comment: I did what you suggested and I could see the correct output in IE after the `Ctrl-R` reload, meaning that it hit the action method. Immediately after this reload, I hit `Ctrl-R` in Chrome and then in IE, and the problem came back. IE also showed the modified StaticContent.htm. I have even opened IE in Private Mode, I should add.

Comment: Use a tool to investigate the HTTP response code (like developer tools in chrome, tab "network"). I'm sure you'll see a "304 Not Modified" response for those IE requests where the action method are not hit. Correct?

Comment: I used the similar tool in IE (pressing F12 brings it up) to see that when hit `Ctrl-R`, I get a status of '304 Not Modified' and for `Ctrl-F5` a status of 200 on all resources loaded. What can be inferred from the fact that I am getting 304 on Ctrl-R refresh?

Comment: Exactly. See the flow here. The url is "/staticpage.htm". First load is a 200 OK and the request are processed by the server and the routing rules are applied and gets the (IE) request to route to the action method. Next request (ctrl+r) becomes a 301 as "/staticpage.htm" hasnt changed since last request. Url routes are not being applied as server already decided to send a 301. Reloading with "ctrl + F5" on the other hand sends a "send me fresh content no matter what"-request results in a 200 OK response where the routing where used. See the flow? Correct?

Comment: I moved on from this and was working on something else, the caching somehow stopped after sometime and I was able to steadily see the correct output in IE. :)